# BeautifulSoup sent post request with specific form ID

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have one page with multiple form. Each form have same "action" but with different "ID"

For example :

```
1. form action="test1.php" id="do_one" method="POST" name="form_one"
2. form action="test1.php" id="do_two" method="POST" name="form_two"
3. form action="test1.php" id="do_three" method="POST" name="form_three"
```

This is how I send request.

```
import requests


params = {'name': 'Budi', 'age': '24'}
r = requests.post(action_url, data=params)
```

How to sent post request with specific form id ?

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` is an HTM parser. For sending requests you use `requests`

Comment: @Volatil3, sure. I mean how to sending request from specific form ID

Comment: `form = soup.select(`#do_two `)` and then `f_name = form[0]['name]`